# how to post a form with payload in angular 2?

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I am playing with angular 2, try to create a sample app that upload a file.
Have below view and component, when i click submit, i don`t see any request is coming out from browser.

if i add (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" to form, i can see onSubmit is invoked, but i don`t see anything pass into it.

***Question: what is the right way to get proper binding so that i can have a valid file upload form?***

Template:

```
<form action="api/upload" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="btn-group" role="group">
    <input type="file" class="btn btn-lg btn-default" required>
    <input type="submit" value="Upload" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary upload-btn">
</form>
```

---

Component:

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {FORM_DIRECTIVES}    from 'angular2/common';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    directives: [FORM_DIRECTIVES],
    template: 'path-to-template'
})

export class AppComponent {
    onSubmit(e) {
        // TODO: get payload from form and upload to server
        console.log(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you need specifically form, or you just want to upload file?

Comment: Have a look at this question, hope it helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36352405/file-upload-with-angular2-to-rest-api

Comment: Looks like  $event parameter is missing here (ngSubmit)="onSubmit($event)"

Answer (score 1):

In my project , I use the XMLHttpRequest to send multipart/form-data.
I think it will fit you to.

html code

```
<input type="file" (change)="selectFile($event)">
```

ts code

```
selectFile($event): void {
  var inputValue = $event.target;
  this.file = inputValue.files[0];
  console.debug("Input File name: " + this.file.name + " type:" + this.file.size + " size:" + this.file.size);
}
```

upload code:

```
const URL = 'http://www.example.com/rest/upload/avatar'; 

uploader:MultipartUploader = new MultipartUploader({url: URL});

item:MultipartItem = new MultipartItem(this.uploader);

if (this.item == null){
   this.item = new MultipartItem(this.uploader);
}
if (this.item.formData == null)
  this.item.formData = new FormData();

this.item.formData.append("file",  this.file);

this.item.callback = this.uploadCallback;
this.item.upload();
```

Here is example : https://github.com/wangzilong/angular2-multipartForm

Comment: I tried your example and got "Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://www.example.com/rest/upload/avatar. This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS.". I tries with enabling CORS on my api but I still get this error

Comment: In my project, I add a filter to add Http header  <br/> HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) response; <br/> res.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:8080");  <br/>
res.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, DELETE, PUT");  <br/>
res.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type");  <br/>
res.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");