# How to upload a file from Angular 2 to Django Server? (enctype="multipart/form-data")

Tags: django, angular, asyncfileupload, angular2-http

I have seen multiple questions on stackoverflow similar to this but I have not been able to solve the following issue.

I can successfully upload a file using this html form:

```html
<form method="POST" action="//127.0.0.1:8000/upload" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
    <input type="file" name="myfile" required>
    <button type="submit">Upload</button>
</form>
```

and here is how the file is handled on the server side:

**views.py**

```python
def upload_file(request):
    f = request.FILES['myfile']
    with open('media/name.jpg', 'wb+') as destination:
        for chunk in f.chunks():
            destination.write(chunk)
    return HttpResponse('Done')
```

Everything works perfectly up to this point. The file gets uploaded and saved as name.jpg on disk. Now, I would like to replace the html above to post the file without a url redirect (using angular 2 http). Following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36352405/file-upload-with-angular2-to-rest-api/39862337#39862337), here is my current implementation:

**file-upload.component.ts**

```js
import { Component, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import {Http, Headers, RequestOptions, Response} from '@angular/http';

@Component({
    selector: 'file-upload',
    template: '<input type="file" name="myfile">' 
})
export class FileUploadComponent {
    constructor(private http: Http, private el: ElementRef) {}
upload() {
    var headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type','multipart/form-data');
    let inputEl = this.el.nativeElement.firstElementChild;
    if (inputEl.files.length > 0) {
        let file:FileList = inputEl.files[0];
        this.http
            .post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/upload', file, {headers: headers})
            .subscribe();
    }
}
```

and call it like this:

```html
<file-upload #myfile (change)="myfile.upload()"></file-upload>
```

I get a 400 bad request error saying (Unable to parse request body), and I think it happens at this line:

```python
f = request.FILES['myfile']
```

since request.FILES requires enctype="multipart/form-data", my first hunch is that I am not passing multipart/form-data correctly.

A lot of older discussions suggest the use of XMLHttpRequest since at the time upload file with http was not supported apparently. I tried that as well and still get the same error.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

I think your problem is:

```
enctype="multipart/form-data"
```

If you're using a form service sometimes the HTML form tags cause problems. I would try it just using:

```
<input type="file" name="myfile" required>
    <button type="submit">Upload</button>
```

I would definitely still use some type of form, just thought this would be quick to debug why it is failing. I would use the angular 2 form library.

Also, here is a multipart upload service that I use:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';


@Injectable()
export class UploadService {

    public makeFileRequest(url: string, params: Array<string>, files: Array<File>) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {            
            let formData: any = new FormData();
            let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            for(let i =0; i < files.length; i++) {
                formData.append('file', files[i], files[i].name);
            }
            xhr.onreadystatechange = () => {
                if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
                    if (xhr.status === 200) {
                        resolve(xhr.response);                        
                    } else {
                        reject(xhr.response);
                    }
                }
            };
            let bearer = 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('currentUser');               
            xhr.open('POST', url, true);
            xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', bearer);
            xhr.send(formData);
        });
    }
}
```

you only need the auth if you're using JWT authentication. If you are not, you want to take out these lines:

```
let bearer = 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('currentUser'); 
xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', bearer);
```