# Accessing FormData object sent from client to server (Express)

Tags: angular, express

I am implementing this solution for uploading files to the server: [File Upload with Angular2 to Rest API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36352405/file-upload-with-angular2-to-rest-api/39862337#39862337)

My question is how do I access the formData items in my server-side POST method?

**Code:**

```
    router.post('/test', function(req, res) {
        // Access the formData object sent from the client
        // Do stuff...
    }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below code :-

```
 router.post('/test', function(req, res) {
     let formidable = require('formidable'); 
     let form = new formidable.IncomingForm(); 
     form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files) {
          // fields will get all fields
          if(files.file && files.file.name){ 
               //file your uploaded file
          }
     });
  });
```

Comment: Everything is just undefined e.g. files.file: undefined

Comment: Have use body parser in your server configuration. Also have you print files.