# File upload with Angular

Tags: php, angular, file-upload

I am trying to implement - https://github.com/spartaksun/ng2-file-uploader#backend-example-using-plain-php

I have installed ng2-file-uploader , in my `component.ts` i am trying to add the code as guided, when i am adding `directives: [UPLOAD_DIRECTIVES]` , it is giving me error - [image: See error]

```
@Component({
  selector: 'demo-app',
  templateUrl: 'app/demo.html',
  directives: [UPLOAD_DIRECTIVES],
})
```

Comment: use this insted-of https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-file-upload

Comment: from where do i get php side code

Comment: see demo : https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-file-upload/blob/master/demo/components/file-upload/simple-demo.ts

Comment: html : https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-file-upload/blob/master/demo/components/file-upload/simple-demo.html

Comment: php code for server side ?

Comment: no changes in php side.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php

Comment: ok you mean i can use that same file, secondly in local host where shall i place my `uploads` folder ? inside app folder and provide path like `localhost:4200/uploads/`  please advise

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146403/discussion-between-shailesh-ladumor-and-user2828442).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [File Upload with Angular2 to Rest API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36352405/file-upload-with-angular2-to-rest-api)

Comment: i am on chat, ping me please

Answer (score 0):

Please read latest doc from angular 2

> directives is no longer Metadata Properties of @Component.

Please read : https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/Component-decorator.html

**Note :**
The plugin you are trying to use is 1 Year Old, so it must be using angular beta version not the final one.

Comment: Please guide any example to upload a file from latest angular using php [please provide simple php code along] , i will be very thankful

Comment: this is again an old example , isnt it />

Comment: I dont think so.